# How can Submit Button's OnClick Event invoke both Server-Side and Client-Side Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap template called Metronic. The asp:LinkButton below was simple button control. Just to be able to invoke the ServerSide event-handler (SubmitButton_Click), I converted it into asp:LinkButton control. But this time it doesn't invoke the javascript code. I tried OnClientClick. But didn't work.

Login.aspx:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right"
  onclick="SubmitButton_Click">Log In<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
 </asp:LinkButton>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
        Login.init();
    });
</script>
```

Part of login.js:

```
var Login = function () {

return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {

       $('.login-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            rules: {
..
..
}
```

Login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ..
}
```

Login.js:

```
var Login = function () {

return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {

       $('.login-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                remember: {
                    required: false
                }
            },

            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "Username is required."
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Password is required."
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                $('.alert-error', $('.login-form')).show();
            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                label.remove();
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                window.location.href = "/Default.aspx";
            }
        });

        $('.login-form input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                if ($('.login-form').validate().form()) {
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        $('.forget-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },

            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Email is required."
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   

            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                label.remove();
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }
        });

        $('.forget-form input').keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                if ($('.forget-form').validate().form()) {
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        jQuery('#forget-password').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').hide();
            jQuery('.forget-form').show();
        });

        jQuery('#back-btn').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').show();
            jQuery('.forget-form').hide();
        });

        $('.register-form').validate({
            errorElement: 'label', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true
                },
                rpassword: {
                    equalTo: "#register_password"
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                tnc: {
                    required: true
                }
            },

            messages: { // custom messages for radio buttons and checkboxes
                tnc: {
                    required: "Please accept TNC first."
                }
            },

            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   

            },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            success: function (label) {
                label.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                label.remove();
            },

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.attr("name") == "tnc") { // insert checkbox errors after the container                  
                    error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter($('#register_tnc_error'));
                } else {
                    error.addClass('help-small no-left-padding').insertAfter(element.closest('.input-icon'));
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }
        });

        jQuery('#register-btn').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').hide();
            jQuery('.register-form').show();
        });

        jQuery('#register-back-btn').click(function () {
            jQuery('.login-form').show();
            jQuery('.register-form').hide();
        });
    }

};

}();
```

Comment: Remember to return true after anything you get done on the `OnClientClick`.

Comment: Or, on the client side you can use `__doPostBack()` to carry on with the `PostBack`.

Comment: Or, on the server side you can use something like `RegisterStartupScript` to call the client side.

Comment: return false; was the missing bit in my case. Thanks. But works only for sth like alert("Hello"). Original js code still ignored. I think because it is placed inside return{}. I don't know what RegisterStartupScript is.

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery selector to handle the click of the anchor that results from the `LinkButton` being rendered to HTML, like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" 
                CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right TheLinkButton"
                onclick="SubmitButton_Click">
    Log In<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

---

> Note: The `CssClass` value has had `TheLinkButton` added to it to allow for a simpler jQuery selector to be made using the dot (`.`) notation as opposed to an ID (`#`) selector. The main reason for this is that when using ASP.NET with master pages, the naming containers mangle the IDs of controls, while class names are unaffected.

---

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    App.init();
    Login.init();
    jQuery('.TheLinkButton').click(function() {
        // Do what you need to do on the client-side 
        // when the link button is clicked here

    });
});
```

Comment: It works for sth like alert("Hello"). But it doesn't work for the js code I need. I think the problem with it, the script is wrapped in a return{}. Cos still ignores client side. Running straight to server side